# il2cpp initialization failed ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Currently trying to integrate a unity wrapper in native iOS project as a framework and getting app crash at this point.

- il2cpp initialization failedglobal-metadata.dat il2cpp initialization failed ios
- I'm currently using unity project created in Unity version 2020.3.15f2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have selected the data folder target to UnityFrameworf in unity project directory.

By doing this hope so your issue will be resolved.